# How to properly configure media files editing and viewing in templates

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-media

I have create a small project , where i am stuck at one point

**Issue :** not able to get images dynamically and display in template

*i.image.url -> at this line in html images are not coming* from folder media

when i runserver the media folder is not getting created and images are not copied from pics to media folder

seetings.py

```
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
DEBUG = True
ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
   os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'web_components')
]
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')

MEDIA_URL='/media/pics/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'LEARN_FROM_TELUSKO',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'PROJECT.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'Template')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'django.template.context_processors.media',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('LEARN_FROM_TELUSKO.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls)
] 

urlpatterns = urlpatterns + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

models.py

```
class courses(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    price = models.IntegerField()
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='pics', height_field=None, width_field=None, max_length=None)
```

views.py

```
def index(request):
    dest = courses.objects.all()
    return render(request,'index.html',{'getdetails':dest})
```

template

```
{% for i in getdetails %}
<div class="col-xl-3 col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
    <div class="product-box">
        <i>
        <img src="{{ i.image.url }}"/>
        </i>
        <h3>{{ i.name }} </h3>
        <span>{{ i.price }}</span>
    </div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Project structure:

[image: Project structure]

I uploaded files to `127.0.0.1/8000/admin`:
[image: Content uploaded from admin from specific user]

Here they are mentioned in the db

[image: My postgres table]

Comment: Have you tried this:ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['127.0.0.1'] and run python manage.py migrate ?

Comment: where is your index.html in your template i did not see it.

Comment: @amadousow  : index.html is their but not able to capture the entire project list screenshot , so it got cut in image but it their after blog.html